# How to shift values of a column up in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is how my table looks:

table name: Following

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | user2 | user1 | user2 | user2 |
| 2  | user3 | user3 | user1 | user3 |
| 3  | user4 | user4 | user4 | user1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But if change a value like:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | user2 | user1 | user2 | user2 |
| 2  | user3 | user3 | null  | user3 |
| 3  | user4 | user4 | user4 | user1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How do I make the value `user4` (and other values below that) go up leaving no **NULL** value in between?
I want the output as:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | user2 | user1 | user2 | user2 |
| 2  | user3 | user3 | user4 | user3 |
| 3  | user4 | user4 | null  | user1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tired this query:

```
UPDATE following t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN following t2 ON T1.user3+1=T2.user3 - 2
SET t1.user3 = t2.user3;
```

but I get some error `Error code 1,292, SQLState 22007] Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: user2`

Comment: Why do you need to do something like this? If the value can be arbitrarily shifted like this then what is the relation between that value and a given row.... which means your design is not normalized to say the least. You need to rethink the problem.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh The values are majorly dependent on column names rather than rows. I cannot explain how this works but for what I am doing, it's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the query written in the mysql,but here is a way can achieve it.

Fist:

```
You show get the Min(ID) and Max(ID).
```

Second:

`Write a loop For i = Min(ID) to Max(ID)`

Third:

```
Update Following set user3 = (Select user3 from Following where ID = i+1) where ID = i
```

Fourth:

```
Set the last one row data to null or something else what you want init.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ordered list with the available not null names

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/AKAMT48570)

```
UPDATE Table1 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `ID`,
                   `user3`,
                   @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
            FROM Table1 
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) as vars
            WHERE `user3` IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY `ID` ) news
  ON Table1.`ID` = news.rn
SET Table1.`user3` = news.`user3`;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**NOTE:** Here I assume `ID` is continuous sequence. If isnt the case you need to create a temporal id column to make that join.